# Boxed equations

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

How do I place a boxed equation on the same line as other equations?

For example, I have a few equations on the left side of my page but then I want the boxed answer on the same line to the right.

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to use `\hfill`.

Code...

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
$y=mx+b$\hfill$\boxed{a+b=c}$
\end{document}
```

Yields...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `flalign*` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe} 
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.3pt}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

      \begin{flalign*}
         & ax^2 + bx + c = 0 & & \boxed{x = \frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}}
      \end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

[image]